# SQL Server Case with Subquery and variable passthrough

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Running SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am trying to make a basic filter so that an in house program can tell what location/ company it is being run from.

Our old DBA setup a company table (Company), and then has one field change based (dbo.Company.isPrimary) on the location of the database. If the location is the primary then that field will have a '1', if not then it will have a '0'

```
SELECT *
      WHEN (SELECT Comp.NAME AS @Name FROM dbo.Company comp WHERE comp.IsPrimary =1 )    @Name like '%Company1%' 
    THEN (SELECT * FROM Company1Table WHERE Records =blah)
Else
WHEN (SELECT Comp.NAME FROM dbo.Company comp WHERE comp.IsPrimary =1 ) @Name like '%Company2%'  
    THEN (SELECT * FROM Company2Table WHERE Records =blah)
END
```

This is my basic starting area. I am trying to keep things standardized across the entire company here. I will most likely end up using this starting point as a way to call other stored procedures / reports, and pass through variables/ values. So I am trying to make something really small and basic, and I have failed.

I hope my post makes sense.

Comment: difficult to understand.

Comment: Could you not have a field in table 1 that tells you exactly what table that company should reference?  Rather than having to rebuild your view every time you add a new company, you could simply dynamically generate the SQL and run it based on the Company passed in.

Comment: Not sure how to answer that. I don't believe so. I am just a really junior level report writer not a DBA. So I have no real say, just working with what I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the question right, you want to use different tables based on the value that matches `IsPrimary = 1` in the `dbo.Company` table.  You may be able to use a [CASE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CASE_TSQL%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1%29;k%28MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-TSQL%29&rd=true), but I don't think it would work.  I think you are stuck with an IF/ELSE.

```
IF (SELECT Comp.NAME FROM dbo.Company comp WHERE comp.IsPrimary =1 ) like '%Company1%'
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Company1Table WHERE Records =blah
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT Comp.NAME FROM dbo.Company comp WHERE comp.IsPrimary =1 ) like '%Company2%'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM Company1Table WHERE Records =blah
    END
    --Company3 would be in an ELSE statement here
END
```

Note: the BEGINs and ENDs are optional when there is only one line.  So, in this example, they could be left out.

Comment: You did read my question right. Sorry for the confusion, its been a horrendously long day, now I am home with Tacos and Cerveza. This reads as if it will perfectly, and I will reply again once I am at work in the AM.

Comment: This did it for me, but I am unable to upvote you as I do not have enough Rep. thank you for your help.

Comment: @Barnie, no problem, glad it worked.  Ernest's answer would have worked too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather strange format for the data.  The following query gets the company information you want, assuming there is a name field in the company tables:

```
select *
from Company1Table ct
where ct.name in (select name from Company c where c.IsPrimary = 1)
union all
select *
from Company2Table ct
where ct.name in (select name from Company c where c.IsPrimary = 0)
```

I would suggest that you wrap this in a view and use the view, well, everywhere.  Then you can start to figure out how to fix this awkwardness of having company data split between tables in different tables.

This assumes that the tables have overalapping information.  Perhaps the `IsPrimary` value isn't even necessary, becasue a given `name` only appears in one table.  In that case, just use a join:

```
select *
from Company1Table
union all
select *
from Company2Table
```

And then start working on how to combine them into a single table.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to understand for me - but i think what you might want is a UNION.

```
select * from companyTable1
union
select * from companyTable2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```
 If Exists (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Company comp WHERE comp.IsPrimary = 1 and Comp.NAME like '%Company1%')
Begin
 SELECT * FROM Company1Table WHERE Records =blah
End
ELSE
BEGIN
   If Exists (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Company comp WHERE comp.IsPrimary = 1 and Comp.NAME like '%Company2%')
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM Company2Table WHERE Records =blah
    END
End
```

Comment: Thank you, I plan on adding this to my growing collection of "tools" for future reference.